# Django format a request in a list

Tags: python, django

I need help to format a response of a django request, This is a exemple :

With a model like this:

```
Book(models):
    name = string
    author = string
    release = date
```

A request :
`Book.objects.filter(author='Hergé').value('name')`

I got :
`[{'name':'Tintin au Tibet'}, {'name':'Tintin au Congo'}, {'name':'Tintin chez les Picarros'}]`

I want this :
`['Tintin au Tibet','Tintin au Congo','Tintin chez les Picarros']`

My question:
How to I get what I want by changing only the request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with [**`.values_list(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
Book.objects.filter(author='Hergé').values_list('name', flat=True)
```

But usually it is not a good idea to use `.values(…)` or `.values_list(…)` to retrieve data, not even to serialize: it erodes the model layer, and thus will prevent fetching related objects, obtaining the display name, etc.

Comment: When used in a API return ? or in any case ? (not my plan :) )
It's what I need thx

Comment: @Kanarpp: usually for that one uses serializers: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/ Of course you decide: depending on the exact specifications, it might be a good idea to use `.values_list`, but it is often not. See https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html